# Using OpenMP to operate nested vector causes core dump

Tags: c++, stl, openmp

Recently,I use `OpenMP` `Parallel For` to accelerate some calculation. Before the `OMP` code running, I have prepared independent storage space for every single `OMP` thread, using *`vector resize`* function.

Here is the problem: when I use `vector< vector<> >` type, program would be lead to `core dump` in several hours, but use `vector< vector<>* >` would not. I'm not familiar enough with `OpenMP` to understand this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code below:

```
//near_geohash_vec.size() == 9
std::vector< std::vector<mtads_frame::PoiInfo* > > poi_info_vec_vec;
poi_info_vec_vec.resize(near_geohash_vec.size());
std::vector< std::vector< DealRespRet* > > deal_ret_vec_vec;
deal_ret_vec_vec.resize(near_geohash_vec.size());

#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < near_geohash_vec.size(); i++) 
{
    std::vector<mtads_frame::PoiInfo*> &poi_info_vec = poi_info_vec_vec[i];
    item_deal_mgr->QueryInfo(near_geohash_vec[i],
                             deal_front_cids_map,
                             poi_info_vec,
                             FLAGS_retrieval_result_length);

       CalcDistance(request,poi_info_vec_vec[i],
                    reco_result_pool_mgr,deal_ret_vec_vec[i]);

    if (ad_rank_.get() != NULL) 
    {
        ad_rank_->Work(deal_ret_vec_vec[i], request->curr_hour());
    } 
    else if (rank_.get() != NULL) 
    {
        rank_->Work(deal_ret_vec_vec[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the code without problem:

```
//near_geohash_vec.size() == 9
std::vector< std::vector< mtads_frame::PoiInfo* >* > poi_info_vec_vec;
std::vector< std::vector< DealRespRet* >* > deal_ret_vec_vec;

for (size_t i = 0; i < near_geohash_vec.size(); ++i) 
{
    poi_info_vec_vec.push_back(new std::vector< mtads_frame::PoiInfo* >());
    deal_ret_vec_vec.push_back(new std::vector< DealRespRet* >());
}

#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < near_geohash_vec.size(); i++) 
{
    std::vector< mtads_frame::PoiInfo* > &poi_info_vec = *(poi_info_vec_vec[i]);
    std::vector< DealRespRet* > &deal_ret_vec = *(deal_ret_vec_vec[i]);

    item_deal_mgr->QueryInfo(near_geohash_vec[i],
                             deal_front_cids_map,
                             poi_info_vec,
                             FLAGS_retrieval_result_length);

    CalcDistance(request, poi_info_vec, reco_result_pool_mgr, deal_ret_vec);
    if (ad_rank_.get() != NULL) 
    {
        ad_poi_rank_->Work(deal_ret_vec, request->curr_hour());
    } 
    else if (rank_.get() != NULL) 
    {
        rank_->Work(deal_ret_vec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hours before coredump. How do you make sure that you are not showing only the correct part of your code, if the error is hard to reproduce?

Comment: When do you allocate the space for the elements of the inner vectors, in implementations? You could edit you question to clarify this a little bit if cannot comment.

Comment: I find problem code by note&run method:note each part of code in system, and run ,watching hours ,if occur coredump,then testing another part of code.At last,I find this part affect coredump occurrence directly. By the way,the coredump information shows segment fault point is not here,it is in other total heathy code, so i suspect the thread stack is corrupted.

Comment: A same (maybe not?) function `CalcDistance` works on both `std::vector< mtads_frame::PoiInfo* >` and `std::vector< PoiInfo >` types?

Comment: In Online system, this type is std::vector< mtads_frame::PoiInfo* >, I will fix it，please don't be mind~

Comment: No obvious problem now. A good start for experienced people to guess the reason of your core dump problem.

Comment: Have you tried performing a post-mortem analysis with a debugger? Those cores are dumped to help you debug problems and not only to fill up your disk. Make sure that you build the program with debug symbols and that no limit on the core size is set (`ulimit -c unlimited`).

Comment: I did it before, which is opening the core file with gdb, debugger showed me that a const parameter is modified, so I think core dump file may not be helpful enough.

Comment: Have you examined the stack trace from the core file? Which line of code causes it? In which thread? Modification of constant parameters signs deeper problems and perhaps has nothing to do with OpenMP per se. How are we supposed to know what `QueryInfo()`, `CalcDistance()`, and the two `Work()` methods do with the two vectors?

Comment: QueryInfo() and CalcDistance() methods are reentrant functions, QueryInfo() is charge of collecting data which type is mtads_frame::PoiInfo*  into poi_info_vec, and for the same reason CalcDistance() collecting DealRespRet* data into deal_ret_vec_vec[i]. Anyway, the first code phase would cause core dump,but the second would not. The difference between the two phases code is the type of inner vector-----whether is pointer or not